Are hunting cabins allowed in Ontario?
Background (edited):
Municipalities in Ontario enforce the Ontario Building Code. Typically, it's the lower-tier municipality (the township) that enforces the building code, not the upper-tier municipality (the county or region).  Municipalities also have by-laws, such as zoning by-laws, that restrict the types of buildings that are allowed in a given zone. So, when it comes to buildings, I believe municipalities enforce rules in both the Ontario Building Code and local zoning by-laws.
Hunting Cabins:
I've heard from builders that there is a way to legally build a hunting cabin without needing to comply with the usual rules in the building code for dwellings. "The cabin only needs to be structurally sound and not be used year-round as a dwelling." An example of a hunting cabin would be a 200-square-foot open-concept bungalow; without utilities, a heat recovery ventilator, furnace, or foundation;  used occasionally for recreation in a rural area.
I've gotten the impression that the rules around hunting cabins have changed in recent years. However, it's difficult to find credible information about what the current rules may be. There's no mention of hunting cabins in the current Ontario Building Code, and it's unclear to me if there ever was in previous versions. Alternatively, I've wondered if municipalities had an unwritten rule, or a written rule in their zoning by-law, that allowed for hunting cabins in specific circumstances.
Are hunting cabins allowed in Ontario?
I understand that each municipality has its own zoning by-law, which would be too broad to explore here. I asked a rural municipality about the regulations for hunting cabins, and they told me that all the same rules for a detached house apply to a hunting cabin. That seems strange to me since it would be highly impractical to build a fully compliant house that would only be used occasionally as a hunting cabin. And it contradicts what I've heard from builders. Yes, these builders could be mistaken, but so could the municipality; I'm looking for definitive information.

I am very doubtful that unorganized territory outside of a municipality don't have building codes in Canada.

"I asked a rural municipality about the regulations for hunting cabins, and they told me that all the same rules for a detached house apply to a hunting cabin."  I recommend you ask them to cite the building code they referenced to provide that answer instead of asking internet randos around the globe....

@ohwilleke I removed that part from the question.

@ohwilleke You're missing how large Ontario is, and how sparsely populated the unorganized territories are. Kenora District has 7,000 people in an area larger than Montana.

@user71659 I'm well aware of that. But usually there is some government of last resort that imposes laws including building codes.
